# HTML CSS footer

Tags: html, css, footer

How do I push a footer to the bottom of my page? Here is an example of what I currently have: [hansmoolman.com](http://www.hansmoolman.com)
As you can see the footer is pushed underneath my 2 left and right containers. How can I fix this. I have used relative positioning for some elements as the red banner had to be pushed over the header bar and given a + z-index. I found some solutions online to stick the footer to the bottom but this does not solve my problem as the footer still appears aver my 2 columns if the content in them is not big enough to fill the whole page.

So what I want is for the footer to always follow BELOW all the rest of the content (the sticking to the bottom I can solve later).

There is a bit of CSS code so havent added it here, but can add it if needed

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: If the question is about `html` and `CSS` it's usually beneficial to add it to the question.

Comment: did u google it?So many solutions available for this.

Comment: @Hans Moolman: See my answer having possible solution below. Thanks!

Comment: This solved it for me 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206281/unable-to-float-twitter-bootstrap-navbar-on-mobile-ipad-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your CSS Looks Like:**

```
#footer {
    background-color: #FFFEF0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -100px; /* >> Remove This*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px; /* >> Remove This*/
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Remove following css rules from `#footer`

```
top: -200px; 
margin-top: -100px;
```

Comment: negative margins are asking for problems generally

Comment: Yip this was exactly it thanks. I guess thats what you get if you copy and paste code from some of your old projects late at night.

Answer (score 1):

Try clear:both for your footer container tag, considering it has display:block; set

Answer (score 1):

To align the contents right. You have to make some changes in your css.

First of all remove :

```
top: -200px;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
```

From your `#footer` .

And change your `#mainContentContainer` to :

```
#mainContentContainer
{
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```